# Removing '\n' character from print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have the following code when writing to a text file:

```
def writequiz(quizname,grade,perscore,score,username):
    details=[quizname,username,grade,perscore,score]

    with open('quizdb','a') as userquiz:
        print(details,file=userquiz)
```

Now the code is doing what I want it to (writing to a new line every time), however if I wanted to write every list to the same line in the text file how would I do this using the print method as used above? I know I could use `file.write`, but how do I remove the newline character in the `print` statement? Slightly hypothetical but it was bugging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `end` parameter of `print` to be an empty string (or some other character):

```
print(details, file=userquiz, end='')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you can see that it defaults to a newline:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print `objects` to the text stream `file`, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`. `sep`, `end`, `file` and `flush`, if present, must be given
>   as keyword arguments.

This is what is being printed to the file currently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `python 2.x`, you can do the following:

```
print >> userquiz, details, # <- notice the comma at the end
```

If using `pytnon 3.x`, you can do this:

```
print(details,file=userquiz, end = " ")
```

Check [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation.

Comment: `print(details, file=userquiz),` for python 2 is not going work, it is invalid syntax, should be `print >>userquiz, details,`

Comment: True, the first syntax was not going to write to file. Thank you. @khachik